# How can one generate an rss feed from a directory of mp3's?

Tags: xml, rss

I have a weekly podcast and I would like to generate the necessary rss feed for it to be listed on itunes.  I have a list of mp3's inside folders @ 
http://themetalexperience.com/episodes/

Is there a way to just list individual mp3's inide the xml file for the rss feed?